# Employing arrows to fold a list of tuples

Tags: haskell, tuples, arrows

Sometimes you want to fold a list of tuples into one tuple using different folding functions. For instance, in order to glue together a list of runState results, getting an (in some sense) combined state and a combined result.

Consider the following implementation:

```
wish :: (a -> a' -> a) -> (b -> b' -> b) -> (a,b) -> [(a', b')] -> (a,b)
wish lfn rfn x xs = foldl (\(a,b) -> (lfn a) *** (rfn b)) x xs
```

Although it works, I feel uncomfortable about this lambda. `lfn *** rfn` by itself has a type of `(a,b) -> (a -> a', b -> b')`, which I can't find a way to properly apply to a tuple without ever resorting to pattern matching. Is there a clear and elegant way I'm missing? It could be a library function of type `(a,a') -> (a -> a, a' -> a') -> (a, a')` or a whole different approach, maybe.

Comment: Some sort of BiApplicative class would do.. There probably is one somewhere on hackage, but I'll leave it to others to cover which ones are good and not-deprecated.

Comment: http://squing.blogspot.com/2008/11/beautiful-folding.html and its instantiation on Hackage, http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ZipFold

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Control.Arrow` does not pay much attention to higher-arity functions. What you really want is a function `foo :: (a -> a' -> a'') -> (b -> b' -> b'') -> (a,b) -> (a',b') -> (a'',b'')`, the analogue of `(***)` for functions of arity 2. There is such a function in Data.Biapplicative (from the package bifunctor), which has the somewhat more general signature `biliftA2 :: Biapplicative w => (a -> b -> c) -> (d -> e -> f) -> w a d -> w b e -> w c f`. Since there is a Biapplicative instance for two-element tuples, that is all you need.

The only complaint I can see against your code as it stands is that it the currying of the lambda is non-obvious; I might prefer the more explicit `\(a,b) (a',b') -> (lfn a a', rfn b b')`.

Edit notes: I had concluded that the needed function did not exist, and suggested defining it; spurred by Carl's comment, I found the one in Biapplicative (the more general type signature had prevented Hoogle from finding it under my suggested signature).

Comment: Going for manual tuple decomposition with `\(a,b) (a',b') -> ...` kinda defies the whole purpose of using some fancy concept to write an all-powerful one-liner. Thanks for referring to Biapplicative, I'll look into it.

Comment: My point was that even though Biapplicative's `(<<**>>)` does have the type you need to apply `(lfn *** rfn)`, the invocation of arrows seems out of place to me here. But that is just my intuition; the arrow-based approach is correct, if not necessarily clear. But I do prefer `(lfn \`biLiftA2\` rfn)` to the explicit lambda.